# WooCommerce.php crashing Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, crash

Can someone please help. My customer has a Wordpress site built using Woocommerce. Recently Wordpress updated and my customer updated his plugin also which caused the whole thing to crash (500 error). I have logged in via FTP and disabled the plugins so the basic site is back up. I have also gone into the plugins and tested them and found only one is crashing the site and that is the WooCommerce.php itself. I have tried rolling back and reinstalling but it continues to crash. WP is version 4.9.8-en_GB. WooCommerce.php version is now 3.4.4 - both the latest. Neither myself or the customer are hugely experienced in this type of site. Oh and the stinger is while he did set up a backup plugin - the thing never completed a back up in the year or so it ran! Help..... we are at a loss.

Comment: Depending on the woocommerce version change, First your theme and all plugins should be compatible. All woocommerce templates located in the theme (if there is any) should be up to date. To finish all customizations will need to be revisited...

Comment: Enable debugging: https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress, and check what fatal error is being given. If you are not able to solve the erorr yourself you can post the error. Note: You could also seek for support at the theme developer/WooCommerce.